# Android fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints() always return false in marsmallow android

Tags: android

I want to use fingerprint auth in my app but, I got problem in Marsmallow android, here is my code

`public static boolean isFingerprintAvailable(Context context) {
        FingerprintManagerCompat fingerprintManager = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context);
        return fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints();
    }`

always return false even though I already registered a fingerprint on my marsmallow android phone.

Comment: Have you added uses permissions ?

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh yes I have, like this 
` <!-- Step 1: Add the following permission to the app  -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />

    <!-- Step 2: This permission is depreciated in Android P  -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />`
 this only happened in api 23/marshmallow

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/authentication-using-fingerprint-in-android-tutorial try this tutorial, it depends on how you are writing the code you can refer it.

Comment: Have you tried using BiometricsManager from androidx?

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh  I'm using java in my projects, so I run project example from this link [https://github.com/anitaa1990/Biometric-Auth-Sample](https://github.com/anitaa1990/Biometric-Auth-Sample). would you please review the code that getting enrolled fingerprint ?

Comment: What phone are you testing on? Was the phone released with Android M, or was one of those phones that had some custom fingerprint implementation on earlier Android versions? In that case it might not work properly with Android's fingerprint API even after upgrading to Android M.